# Compilation debug = true -- change without recompiling?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have a build of some ASP.NET code that was compiled with

```
<compilation debug = "true">
```

We have a major performance issue that appears to be fixed by changing this value and recompiling.  The issue is that we cannot roll back to rebuild the current deployed code.  Is there anything I can do to the current build?

I see many references to modifying the machine.config and adding

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
          <deployment retail=”true”/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I see the machine.config available in the 2.0 and 4.0 framework folders but not 3.5 (which this is built for).

This is currently running in IIS7.

What can be done if anything?

Comment: can u confirm that the slow version of the code was not compiled under 'DEBUG' mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`touch` all your aspx files after you removed the debug setting, then restart/kill the w3wp process. It should recompile them all now.

As for the DLL's in the bin directory, you are out of luck.